# java chatbot does not work on facebook messenger webhook

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

we followed this link(https://github.com/thekosmix/Java-FbChatBot) to build a java chatbot, when we try it on webhook of messenger , we hit the following error: The URL couldn't be validated. Response does not match challenge, expected value="1211923363", received=""
our webhook is: https://41ab4ddb.ngrok.io/bot/webhook?hub.verify_token=nhitoken&hub.challenge=123456

Comment: it worked by this url:  https://41ab4ddb.ngrok.io/bot/webhook?hub.verify_token=whatever_string_you_or_your_friends_wish&hub.challenge=joeyang

Comment: unfortunately, webhook is ok on FB, but we saw some  errors on 9090 console: [INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds.
webhook servlet created!!
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/1815549365137695?access_token=YOUR_FB_PAGE_TOKEN
[ERROR] /bot/webhook
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at in.strollup.fb.utils.FbChatHelper.getReplies(FbChatHelper.java:117)